# What's faster, SELECT DISTINCT or GROUP BY in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, distinct

If I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  profession varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  employer varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)
```

and I want to get all unique values of `profession` field, what would be faster (or recommended):

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.profession FROM users u
```

or

```
SELECT u.profession FROM users u GROUP BY u.profession
```

?

Comment: You could test for yourself as quickly as ask the question. Irritatingly, it is almost impossible to construct a scenario in which DISTINCT outperforms GROUP BY - which is annoying because clearly this is not the purpose of GROUP BY. However, GROUP BY can produce misleading results, which I think is reason enough for avoiding it.

Comment: There's another duplicate with a different answer. see [MySql - Distinct vs Group By](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114506/mysql-distinct-vs-group-by/25114686) <<< it says GROUP BY is better

Comment: Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581521/whats-faster-select-distinct-or-group-by-in-mysql/37611287#answer-37611287) if you want to measure the time difference between DISTINCT and GROUP BY running your query.

Comment: Also, don't use DISTINCT and GROUP BY in the same query. It can cause huge slowness issues for some queries.

Answer (score 304, accepted):

They are essentially equivalent to each other (in fact this is how some databases implement `DISTINCT` under the hood).

If one of them is faster, it's going to be `DISTINCT`.  This is because, although the two are the same, a query optimizer would have to catch the fact that your `GROUP BY` is not taking advantage of any group members, just their keys. `DISTINCT` makes this explicit, so you can get away with a slightly dumber optimizer.

When in doubt, test!

Comment: DISTINCT will be faster only if you DON'T have an index (as it doesn't sort). When you do have an index and it's used, they're synonyms.

Comment: The definition of `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` differ in that `DISTINCT` doesn't have to sort the output, and `GROUP BY` by default does. However, in MySQL even a `DISTINCT`+`ORDER BY` might _still_ be faster than a `GROUP BY` due to the extra hints for the optimizer as explained by SquareCog.

Comment: DISTINCT is much faster with large amount data.

Comment: I tested this, and found that on an indexed column, mysql, group by was about 6x slower than distinct with a fairly complicated query. Just adding this as a datapoint. About 100k rows. So test it and see for yourselves.

Comment: see [MySql - Distinct vs Group By](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114506/mysql-distinct-vs-group-by/25114686) <<< it says GROUP BY is better

Comment: Today I had a DISTINCT query in MariaDB (no sorting, but LIMIT 0, 2000) which took 100 seconds to execute. After replacing DISTINCT by GROUP BY it just took 0.5 seconds.
I guess this strongly depends on the executed query, tables, indexes and data, but the difference is immense. I suggest that you always test both versions.
However I would expect that both are equal on a good DBMS, if you are not using HAVING or aggregate functions.

Comment: Don't assume that DISTINCT (or GROUP BY) will be faster when they're logically equivalent. Use EXPLAIN and look at their query plans to verify. I just found a case where MySQL 8.0 was faster with DISTINCT avoiding a sort with proper index, but GROUP BY still showed a sort in its query plan with the same index.

Answer (score 115):

If you have an index on `profession`, these two are synonyms.

If you don't, then use `DISTINCT`.

`GROUP BY` in `MySQL` sorts results. You can even do:

```
SELECT u.profession FROM users u GROUP BY u.profession DESC
```

and get your professions sorted in `DESC` order.

`DISTINCT` creates a temporary table and uses it for storing duplicates. `GROUP BY` does the same, but sortes the distinct results afterwards.

So

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.profession FROM users u
```

is faster, if you don't have an index on `profession`.

Comment: You can add `ORDER BY NULL` to the `GROUP BY` to avoid the sort.

Comment: Still slower even with grouping by null

Comment: @ThanhTrung: what is slower than what?

Comment: @Quassnoi groupby slower than distinct even if avoiding sort

Comment: Note: Order qualifiers on GROUP BY were deprecated in MySQL 8.

Answer (score 27):

All of the answers above are correct, for the case of DISTINCT on a single column vs GROUP BY on a single column. 
Every db engine has its own implementation and optimizations, and if you care about the very little difference (in most cases) then you have to test against specific server AND specific version! As implementations may change...

BUT, if you select more than one column in the query, then the DISTINCT is essentially different! Because in this case it will compare ALL columns of all rows, instead of just one column.

So if you have something like:

```
// This will NOT return unique by [id], but unique by (id,name)
SELECT DISTINCT id, name FROM some_query_with_joins

// This will select unique by [id].
SELECT id, name FROM some_query_with_joins GROUP BY id
```

It is a common mistake to think that DISTINCT keyword distinguishes rows by the first column you specified, but the DISTINCT is a general keyword in this manner.

So people you have to be careful not to take the answers above as correct for all cases... You might get confused and get the wrong results while all you wanted was to optimize!

Comment: Although this question *is* about MySQL it should be noted that the second query will work *only* in MySQL. Nearly every other DBMS will reject the second statement because it's an invalid use of the GROUP BY operator.

Comment: Well, "nearly" is a problematic definition :-)
It would be much more helpful if you state a specific DBMS that you have *tested* to see that it generates an error for this statement.

Comment: Postgres, Oracle, Firebird, DB2, SQL Server for starters. MySQL :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6897c/1 Postgres: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6897c/1 Oracle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6897c/1 SQL Server: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6897c/1

Comment: And to confuse us :) , mysql allows using `select distinct(a), b` which means `select distinct a, b`, which means distinct on the pair.

Answer (score 17):

Go for the simplest and shortest if you can -- DISTINCT seems to be more what you are looking for only because it will give you EXACTLY the answer you need and only that!

Answer (score 9):

well distinct can be slower than group by on some occasions in postgres (dont know about other dbs).

tested example:

```
postgres=# select count(*) from (select distinct i from g) a;

count 

10001
(1 row)

Time: 1563,109 ms

postgres=# select count(*) from (select i from g group by i) a;

count
10001
(1 row)

Time: 594,481 ms
```

http://www.pgsql.cz/index.php/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks_I

so be careful ... :)

Comment: GROUP BY is also faster than DISTINCT in AWS Redshift, because GROUP BY uses a `XN HashAggregate` and DISTINCT uses a `XN Unique`. It is the same problem that older versions of Postgres have.

Answer (score 7):

Group by is expensive than Distinct since Group by does a sort on the result while distinct avoids it. But if you want to make group by yield the same result as distinct give ***order by null*** ..

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.profession FROM users u
```

**is equal to**

```
SELECT u.profession FROM users u GROUP BY u.profession order by null
```

Comment: is equal to `SELECT profession FROM users GROUP BY profession`

Answer (score 6):

In *MySQL*, "`Group By`" uses an extra step: `filesort`. I realize `DISTINCT` is faster than `GROUP BY`, and that was a surprise.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the queries are not exactly the same. At least for MySQL.

Compare:

1. describe select distinct productname from northwind.products
2. describe select productname from northwind.products group by productname

The second query gives additionally "Using filesort" in Extra.

Comment: They are the same in terms of what they get, not in terms of how they get it. An ideal optimizer would execute them the same way, but MySQL optimizer is not ideal. Based on your evidence, it would seem that DISTINCT would go faster -- O(n) vs O(n*log n).

Comment: So, "using filesort" is essentially bad thing?

Comment: In this case it is, because you don't need to sort (you would if you needed the groups).  MySQL sorts in order to place the same entries together, and then get groups by scanning the sorted file.  You just need distincts, so you just have to hash your keys while doing a single table scan.

Comment: Add `ORDER BY NULL` to the `GROUP BY` version and they will be the same.

Answer (score 3):

After heavy testing we came to the conclusion that GROUP BY is faster

SELECT sql_no_cache
opnamegroep_intern
  FROM `telwerken`
  WHERE `opnemergroep` IN (7,8,9,10,11,12,13) group by opnamegroep_intern

635 totaal 0.0944 seconds
Weergave van records 0 - 29 ( 635 totaal, query duurde 0.0484 sec)

SELECT sql_no_cache
distinct (opnamegroep_intern)
  FROM `telwerken`
  WHERE `opnemergroep` IN (7,8,9,10,11,12,13)

635 totaal 0.2117 seconds ( almost 100% slower )
Weergave van records 0 - 29 ( 635 totaal, query duurde 0.3468 sec)

Answer (score 2):

(more of a functional note)

There are cases when you have to use GROUP BY, for example if you wanted to get the number of employees per employer:

```
SELECT u.employer, COUNT(u.id) AS "total employees" FROM users u GROUP BY u.employer
```

In such a scenario `DISTINCT u.employer` doesn't work right. Perhaps there is a way, but I just do not know it. (If someone knows how to make such a query with DISTINCT please add a note!)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple approach which will print the 2 different elapsed time for each query.

```
DECLARE @t1 DATETIME;
DECLARE @t2 DATETIME;

SET @t1 = GETDATE();
SELECT DISTINCT u.profession FROM users u; --Query with DISTINCT
SET @t2 = GETDATE();
PRINT 'Elapsed time (ms): ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(millisecond, @t1, @t2) AS varchar);

SET @t1 = GETDATE();
SELECT u.profession FROM users u GROUP BY u.profession; --Query with GROUP BY
SET @t2 = GETDATE();
PRINT 'Elapsed time (ms): ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(millisecond, @t1, @t2) AS varchar);
```

OR try [SET STATISTICS TIME (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx)

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
SELECT DISTINCT u.profession FROM users u; --Query with DISTINCT
SELECT u.profession FROM users u GROUP BY u.profession; --Query with GROUP BY
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
```

It simply displays the number of milliseconds required to parse, compile, and execute each statement as below:

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 2 ms.
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT DISTINCT will always be the same, or faster, than a GROUP BY.  On some systems (i.e. Oracle), it might be optimized to be the same as DISTINCT for most queries.  On others (such as SQL Server), it can be considerably faster.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a rule

For each query .... try separately distinct and then group by ... compare the time to complete each query and use the faster ....

In my project sometime I use group by and others distinct

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to do any group functions (sum, average etc in case you want to add numeric data to the table), use SELECT DISTINCT. I suspect it's faster, but i have nothing to show for it.

In any case, if you're worried about speed, create an index on the column.

Answer (score 0):

**If** the problem allows it, try with EXISTS, since it's optimized to end as soon as a result is found (And don't buffer any response), so, if you are just trying to normalize data for a WHERE clause like this

```
SELECT FROM SOMETHING S WHERE S.ID IN ( SELECT DISTINCT DCR.SOMETHING_ID FROM DIFF_CARDINALITY_RELATIONSHIP DCR ) -- to keep same cardinality
```

A faster response would be:

```
SELECT FROM SOMETHING S WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM DIFF_CARDINALITY_RELATIONSHIP DCR WHERE DCR.SOMETHING_ID = S.ID )
```

This isn't always possible but when available you will see a faster response.

Answer (score 0):

in mySQL i have found that GROUP BY will treat NULL as distinct, while DISTINCT does not.
Took the exact same DISTINCT query, removed the DISTINCT, and added the selected fields as the GROUP BY, and i got many more rows due to one of the fields being NULL.

So.. I tend to believe that there is more to the DISTINCT in mySQL.