# MYSQL: SELECT Method - but don't show duplicates / GROUP or DISTINCT?

Tags: mysql, select, distinct, sql-like

How can I select and don't show duplicates?
Actually, it's showing like that: apple | apple | apples | apple

This is my code:

```
$search = $_GET['q'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM query WHERE searchquery LIKE '%$search%' AND searchquery <> '$search'";
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You already said the magic word: DISTINCT.

```
SELECT DISTINCT columnname
FROM query
WHERE ....
```

Note that it probably won't work if you use `SELECT DISTINCT *` because when you select `*` that means select all columns, including columns which have a unique constraint such as the primary key. Only select the columns you need - stay away from `*` in general, and especially so when using `DISTINCT`.

Comment: 4 years later and your answer is still resolving problems. Thanks!

Comment: Adding to the answer: you can either use DISTINCT or GROUP BY (all fields selected), of course distinct would be more compact. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581521/whats-faster-select-distinct-or-group-by-in-mysql?rq=1) talks a little bit more about this.