# mySql - Select but don't show duplicates of specific row

Tags: mysql, select

I need to SELECT from a db and don't show rows that are identical in SOME rows (or actually hide the rows that are identical to eachother except 1 item...)

Let's give an example:

```
ID C1 C2 C3
1  3  3  4
1  5  5  4
1  2  3  4
1  6  5  4
1  2  3  4
```

After SELECT i want:

```
ID C1 C2 C3
1  X  3  4
1  X  5  4
```

where "X" has no importance...i have to show that column but i don't care which one is shown.

Is this possible with a simple SELECT query?

To sum up, if i ask the question regarding this specific example, What can i do to SELECT from that table and show only one of the rows if it has identical duplicates in ID, C2 and C3?

SIDENOTE: this [MYSQL: SELECT Method - but don't show duplicates / GROUP or DISTINCT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581718/mysql-select-method-but-dont-show-duplicates-group-or-distinct) doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `GROUP BY`?

```
SELECT Id, MAX(C1), C2, C3
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY Id, C2, C3
```

Since you don't care about C1, in this query, I get the largest C1 value.

Comment: i have a lot to learn about mySql..... this is something basic and i didn't know about it. Thank you it helped me a lot.