# How do I get just one result when running a sql query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT user_ids FROM `items`
```

When I run that query, if a user has multiple items listed, I get the user_id listed that many times, but what I really want is just ONE user_id for each so it basically represents all the user_ids who have >1 entry in the items table (and what I really want is the corresponding email)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to use distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_ids FROM items
```

Comment: For more explanations see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581521/whats-faster-select-distinct-or-group-by-in-mysql

Comment: amazing. thats exactly what i wanted. now i want an email address for each of those results... or is there a more efficient query like "display email from users where user_id ..." seems like the transition is tricky from the items table to the users table (where the emails are stored)

Comment: select email_addr from items where user_ids in (select Distinct user_ids FROM items).  There may be a better way but I can't think of one right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Distinct user_ids FROM items
```

Answer (score 1):

From your context of > 1 entry (ie: more than 1 entry), you'll need a group by, not just distinct... distinct will include everyone, even if they ONLY have ONE entry

```
select User_IDs
   from items
   group by User_IDs
   having count(*) > 1
```