# MySQL using GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql

Why shouldn't I use GROUP BY in place of DISTINCT when writing a query that does not contain an aggregate function?

What is the best practice?

Comment: I thought Group By was necessary when you list out other column names along with a distinct column name.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to remove duplicates, use DISTINCT, since its usually faster.
GROUP BY should be used when you are going to write aggregate operations/functions.

Also, not to be rude or anything but a simple search would have also gotten you the following results

[Whats faster select distinct or group by in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581521/whats-faster-select-distinct-or-group-by-in-mysql)

[Is there any difference between group by and distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct)