# How to improve the performance of my query

Tags: sql, database-design, sql-server-2014, table-index

The query below to get the distinct zip codes from the `Address` table takes roughly 4 mins and 42 seconds. There are 1,006,699 records in the `Address` table.  The composite key for the table is `Address1, Address2, City, ZipCode`.

There have been times when the query takes 5 seconds to run or even 1 mill seconds.

How do I improve the performance of the query?

Here is the SQL query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ZipCode FROM Address
```

Here is the schema for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Address]
(
    [AddressID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Address1] [NVARCHAR](1000) NOT NULL,
    [Address2] [NVARCHAR](1000) NOT NULL,
    [City] [NVARCHAR](1000) NOT NULL,
    [StateCd] [NVARCHAR](2) NULL,
    [ZipCode] [NVARCHAR](10) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([Address1] ASC, [Address2] ASC, [City] ASC, [ZipCode] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Address] ADD DEFAULT ('') FOR [Address2]
GO
```

I can't seem to add an image of the execution plan.

Comment: You you must use the exact same columns for primary key you could move ZIP-Code first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ZipCode FROM Address
```

You want an index on `ZipCode` or at least where `ZipCode` is the first column:

```
create index idx_address_zipcode on address(zipcode);
```

The resulting execution plan should be a scan of the index, which is much faster than processing the original table (and aggregating to get the distinct zip codes).

You could also change your existing index to `(zipcode, city, address1, address2)`.  This makes the index more useful (in my opinion), because `zipcode` is more likely to be used for filtering than `address1`.  However, that index will be larger than one only on `zipcode`.

Comment: So this would be a nonclustered index?

Comment: Yes; you can only have one clustered index, and you already have it.

Comment: @rds80 . . . Yes.  I would advise you to have the `AddressId` be the clustered index, to avoid fragmentation when the data is modified.

Comment: When I only had AddressID has the primary key, the query to get all the records was taking over a minute long.

Answer (score 0):

For maximum performance, you could create an indexed view so that the aggregation is materialized:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_Address_ZipCode
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT ZipCode, COUNT_BIG(*) AS ZipCodeCount
FROM dbo.Address
GROUP BY ZipCode;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx ON dbo.vw_Address_ZipCode(ZipCode);
GO
```

If you are using Enterprise Edition, the optimizer can consider the indexed view without referencing the view directly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ZipCode FROM Address;
```

In lesser editions, you'll need to query the view and add a `NOEXPAND` query hint so the index is considered for optimization:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ZipCode FROM dbo.vw_Address_ZipCode WITH(NOEXPAND);
```

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views) for indexed view requirements.

Comment: Very cool! I wouldn’t have to do aggregations like how many records are there per zip code.  What I’m trying to achieve is an autocomplete feature on the UI with the zip code.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is an aggregation (single row from multiple source rows). Even if you don't use it, `COUNT_BIG()` is required for the view to be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

1.If possible convert `ZipCode` datatype from `nvarchar` to `bigint`.
2.try group by `ZipCode`

```
 SELECT ZipCode FROM Address GROUP BY ZipCode;
```

Comment: Some of the zip codes have 5 numbers "-" 4 numbers. Is there a performance difference between distinct and group by?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114506/distinct-vs-group-by/25114686#25114686  yes it does check this link

Comment: @rds80 if you have "-" in zip code validate it from the client side or validate it with your code at server side and remove "-" if found in the zip code. For values in the database I would suggest replacing "-"  with SQL query or to be safe side do it with code