# Django select distinct in mysql

Tags: mysql, django

How would I do the following query in django:

```
Asset.objects.all().distinct('checksum') # get all distinct checksum items
```

The equivalent in `SQL` would be:

```
SELECT * FROM asset GROUP BY checksum
```

Note that I need **all** fields here, so I cannot do something like `Asset.objects.values_list('checksum').distinct()`. How would I do this?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking for here. Can you provide an example dataset, and your desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get the first item of every `checksum`?

```
items = Asset.objects.all()
items.query.group_by = ['checksum']
print items
[<Asset: ...]
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. It didn't raise an error, but did not GROUP BY the results -- i.e., I have more than one item with the same checksum.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you want to get? The code works, I've just tested it. It returns one item of each checksum -- distinct does same too. Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581521/whats-faster-select-distinct-or-group-by-in-mysql): in most cases they're synonyms.