# MySQL - SUM of rows excluding duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows

```
+----+---------+-------------+--------+
| id | user_id | ip_address  | amount |
+----+---------+-------------+--------+
|  1 |       2 | 192.168.1.1 | 0.5    |
|  2 |       2 | 192.168.1.1 | 0.5    |
|  3 |       2 | 192.168.1.2 | 0.5    |
|  4 |       2 | 192.168.1.3 | 0.5    |
+----+---------+-------------+--------+
```

I want to only unique ip_address SUM of amount and count duplicates as only 1.

From above table there are 4 rows from which first 2 IP addresses are same but I want to count it only one.

I am trying to SUM of amount field like this.

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_amount FROM table
```

I am getting `2` as output.

But I want `1.5` as output, can you please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: For same IP will the amount be same?

Comment: @Beginner yes amount will be same

Comment: One option (and probably the best) is to do a `SUM()` over a subquery with `DISTINCt` in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to aggregate by IP address first and then re-aggregate:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_amount
FROM (SELECT ip_address, MAX(amount) as amount
      FROM table
      GROUP BY ip_address
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

The same can be achieved by the use of `DISTINCT` as well. It is a bit faster compared to `GROUPBY` provided you do not have any indexing on the `ipaddr` field

checkout this link-
 [What's faster, SELECT DISTINCT or GROUP BY in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581521/whats-faster-select-distinct-or-group-by-in-mysql)

```
SELECT SUM(amt) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ipaddr,amt FROM ipaddr_sum) t
```

[image]
[image]

Now the above difference was for just 4 rows. Imagine if the table has lakhs of rows, it would definitely be helpful (**NOTE : Provided youdo not have indexing in your `ipaddr` field** )

Comment: The linked answer is out of date. I defy you to construct a scenario in which DISTINCT outperforms GROUP BY.

Comment: Look at the images...the difference was for just 4 rows, it would mean a lot if working for lakhs of rows

Comment: Dont blatantly say It wouldnt, give an example to prove your point