# Using Distinct or Group by in SQL . Which one is better and faster? State it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, distinct, database-performance

I'm Just using the table which having more than 200 thousand  records each.I need to Fetch `Unique` records by joining those tables .Which keyword would work faster in this case using `Distinct` or `Group by` ?.It should be looked from performance wise better and faster one.Kindly suggest me.

Comment: Write both and compare. What do you want us to do?

Comment: Need to know which keyword should be used to get unique values in faster way and effective.?

Comment: check it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581521/whats-faster-select-distinct-or-group-by-in-mysql

Comment: I seriously doubt that the guys at Microsoft would have made DISTINCT slower, what would be the point of it if they had? As for which is better from a readability point of view I would say DISTINCT is better if you have no need for aggregates as better expresses the intent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you already have everything you need in order to test it yourself.

Comment: But i have mentioned specific scenario here about which keyword should be used @Zohar peled

Comment: The person asking the question tends to be in the best position to answer ["Which is faster?"](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) questions. As has been said, run the two queries and check the execution plans, as well as the IO statistics. Then if you different execution plans, or significantly different execution times (that are repeatable, not just down to a one off high server load for example), then it might be a better question to ask why there is a difference in a new question, and including the execution plans and IO statistics in the new question.

Comment: As Trima wrote in his/her answer, both queries have the same execution plan. you could have and should have tested that yourself before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both queries has the exactly same execution plan.

```
select distinct a,b,c from bigTable

select a,b,c from bigTable
group by a,b,c
```

works with the same process, so you can choose the sintax you prefer.
For being a best Query tunning user, just use "Show execution plan" button from the SQL Server Management Studio. It is really usefull.