# MySQL efficient join with "in" without duplicates

Tags: mysql, join

I have an `event` table

```
+----------+------------+
| event_id | event_name |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | event1     |
|        2 | event2     |
|        3 | event3     |
|        4 | event4     |
+----------+------------+
```

And an `event_performer` table

```
+--------------------+----------+--------------+
| event_performer_id | event_id | performer_id |
+--------------------+----------+--------------+
|                  1 |        1 |            1 |
|                  2 |        1 |            2 |
|                  3 |        2 |            1 |
|                  4 |        2 |            2 |
|                  5 |        3 |            3 |
|                  6 |        3 |            4 |
|                  7 |        4 |            3 |
|                  8 |        4 |            4 |
+--------------------+----------+--------------+
```

I want to get all the events with performer ids 1 and 2, so I run the following query:

```
select event.* from event
join event_performer
on event.event_id = event_performer.event_id 
and performer_id in (1,2)
order by event_name
```

When I do that, I obviously get duplicate events (two for event_id 1 and two for event_id 2). What's the most efficient way in MySQL remove the duplicates so that I get each event record once?

One idea is to use `select distinct event.*` How efficient is that for a large number of fields and records?

Note that the example tables are oversimplified. Each table has MANY more fields and MANY more records.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Group BY

```
select event.event_id, event.event_name from event
join event_performer
on event.event_id = event_performer.event_id 
and performer_id in (1,2)
GROUP BY event_name, event.event_id
order by event_name
```

However do note that if you have created an index on your column then using GROUP BY is similar to using DISTINCT. But if you have not created an index then I would recommend you to go with using DISTINCT as it is comparatively faster than GROUP BY.

Comment: Thank you. In my case, I am selecting all the fields in the event table (there are a lot). Should that whole list be included in both the select statement and the group by statement?

Comment: When you say index, if there are many fields, what index would you be referring to? Just the primary key or a multi-column index?

Comment: @stepanian:- Yes, the index on the column which you are trying to check for duplicates. You can refer: [What's faster, SELECT DISTINCT or GROUP BY in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581521/whats-faster-select-distinct-or-group-by-in-mysql)

Comment: The field event_id is a primary key, auto_increment, so it is an index. Can I group by just event_id, or should the group by include all the columns?

Comment: @stepanian:- In that case, I would recommend you to go with DISTINCT as it would be faster than GROUP BY. But if you are using GROUP BY then yes you have to list all the column names.

Comment: So "select distinct event.*" as in my original suggestion doesn't add a very big overhead?

Comment: @stepanian:- Yes that would be the best way to proceed with in my opinion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92801/discussion-between-stepanian-and-rahul-tripathi).