# SQL Query to get unique list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named 'resources'

```
Machine     Host        Enabled
mach1       host1       TRUE
mach2       host1       FALSE
mach3       host1       FALSE
mach4       host2       TRUE
mach5       host2       TRUE
```

I want to get the list of hosts where Enabled is True for all the resources/machines associated with them.

I tried the sql query-

```
select distinct Host from resources where Enabled = TRUE;
```

But that query gives me back both host1 and host2 as the answer whereas I am expecting the answer to be just host2. Can anyone help me with a sql query which can achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Host
FROM resources
GROUP BY Host        
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN Enabled = True THEN 1 END)
```

or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Host 
FROM resources AS r1
WHERE Enabled = TRUE AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM resources AS r2
                  WHERE r1.Host = r2.Host AND r2.enabled = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks. Both the queries work. What is the difference in between using Group By and Distinct ?

Comment: @sid Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581521/whats-faster-select-distinct-or-group-by-in-mysql) for an answer to your question. Also, you may accept any of the available answers if they help you solve your problem.

Comment: All the answers posted here worked. But the first solution posted here is most useful for me, hence accepted this answer.

Answer (score 2):

TRY THIS ONE AND LET ME KNOW.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Host)
FROM Resources
WHERE Enabled = TRUE AND Host NOT IN (Select Host FROM Resources WHERE Enabled = FALSE)
```

Comment: This works too. However, I will add a limit 1 in the end of the second select statement. It will probably make the query faster.

Comment: Yes, That will make query faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select distinct Host from resources res1 where not exist (
   select 1 from resources res2 WHERE res1.host = res2.host AND Enabled = FALSE limit 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too

```
select host from resources e
having count(e.host)=(select count(enebled) from resources 
                    where enebled='TRUE' and host = e.host)
group by host;
```