# Get only one record from a same date records in the collection - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Is there a way I could **retrieve** only *one* record from `date` records with the `same` value in the collection?

My records goes like this,

```
id | date       | event_name   | type
----------------------------------------
1  | 2016-01-23 | event 1      | event 1
2  | 2016-01-23 | event 1      | event 2
3  | 2016-03-15 | event 2      | event 1
4  | 2016-03-15 | event 2      | event 2
```

So as you can see, there are records with same date and I want to fetch **only one** on that same date records. So I expect to get,

```
2016-01-23, event 1
2016-03-15, event 2
```

I tried,

```
$events = events::select( events.*',
            DB::raw('(select date from events where date = events.date) as events'))
            ->get();
```

but unfortunately its not working. It gives me an `empty` array from

```
dd(var_dump($events->toArray()));
```

Any ideas, help please?

Comment: where `date`(this should be variable) = events.date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual query:

```
SELECT * FROM events GROUP BY date
```

For Laravel:

```
$events = DB::table('events')->groupBy('date')->get();
```

Comment: It is not possible to order the events, to that i only get the last events instead of the first events. When adding `->orderBy('id', 'DESC')` I still get the first events. How do you manage to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to get **one result** for every **redundant** date value in your table, then use the `DISTINCT` keyword in your query.

Try this if you are using MySql:

```
select DISTINCT date from events where date IS NOT NULL
```

**Note:** DISTINCT considers `null` value also as a distinct candidate. So, it's advisable to `check` for `null` on your `where` clause.

Also, [`DISTNCT` is faster than `Group By`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581521/whats-faster-select-distinct-or-group-by-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

If using Eloqunt, you can use the built in `groupBy` method:

```
Events::groupBy('browser')->get();
```

Comment: Shouldn't group by be used for performing some calculations? And the question was to get only one date value, not grouped date into one value right?

Comment: There is no requirement with groupby to do a calculation - either in laravel or the underlying database. If no calc function is provided, it will simply grab the first one - it kind of collapses it.

Comment: @HariHarker Sidenote - I see what you are saying now - but looking at the question, he/she seems happy with the idea of loosing those extra records

Comment: What's bad about using DISTINCT with a where clause to omit null values in the result? I feel it's a bit more cleaner.