# Distinct on two columns

Tags: mysql

How to select unique results from both columns:

```
+---------+--------------+
| team_id | opponents_id |
+---------+--------------+
|       1 |            2 |
|       1 |            3 |
|       1 |            4 |
|       1 |            5 |
|       1 |            6 |
|       2 |            1 |
|       2 |            3 |
|       2 |            4 |
|       2 |            5 |
|       2 |            6 |
|       3 |            1 |
|       3 |            2 |
|       3 |            4 |
|       3 |            5 |
|       3 |            6 |
|       4 |            1 |
|       4 |            2 |
|       4 |            3 |
|       4 |            5 |
|       4 |            6 |
|       5 |            1 |
|       5 |            2 |
|       5 |            3 |
|       5 |            4 |
|       5 |            6 |
|       6 |            1 |
|       6 |            2 |
|       6 |            3 |
|       6 |            4 |
|       6 |            5 |
+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: What do you class as 'unique'? For example, is `1-3` the same as `3-1`?

Comment: The rows you posted are already distinct. What is the outcome you expect?

Comment: Can you paste the sample expected output?

Comment: I need it to take an unique team_id and an random opponents_id.

For example:

1 2 - 
2 4 - 
3 6 - 
4 5 - 
5 1 -
6 3

Answer (score 2):

Just use distinct

```
 select distinct team_id,opponents_id
   from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to suppress duplicate based on the two column then you should group your value with composite index column1, column2

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM MA_TABLE
GROUP BY column1, column2
```

It should return you a list of unique resultset

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2` produces the same result but it is much faster.

Comment: @axiac do you have a article for that?  what I've read is in most engines they produce similar/same execution plans. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581521/whats-faster-select-distinct-or-group-by-in-mysql  Nevermind found one: http://charlesnagy.info/it/mysql/difference-between-distinct-and-group-by

Comment: It still doesn't work the way I need it to work: 
http://puu.sh/wAOva/8befe52df2.png

And when I group by team_id, the Opponents_id are all random and not unique..
http://puu.sh/wAODG/62d98d3ea8.png