# How to get distinct id based on the order of increasing times of ID in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

How to get the distinct id from a group of id based on the order of increasing number of times it present.

```
For Example , input: 3,1,1,2,2,2
```

Here id 2 present 3 times , id 1 present 2 times and id 3 present 1 time..

```
here is my output 2,1,3
```

How to get these with a single query using mysql

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: How did you get this? `3,1,1,2,2,2` is it user input or is it retrieved from a list of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct id, COUNT(id) from your_table 
group by id 
order by COUNT(id)
```

heres a simple query with the count as well if you want to check its in the correct order.

Comment: This one seems to be a better answer than me... Didn't think about the `ORDER BY` part...

Comment: @VASIS Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

At first, we need to analyse how you have got this input:

```
3,1,1,2,2,2
```

The CSV input can be pre-filtered, if it is through:

- User Input
- Query Output

If it was a User Input, then there's no way MySQL can directly access the value, unless it is stored as data. In that case, you will be having some kind of PHP or other programming language that sends the data to MySQL. So, assuming it for PHP, what I would do is:

```
<?php
  $csv = "3,1,1,2,2,2";
  $arr = explode(",", $csv);
  $arr = array_unique($arr);
?>
```

Now you will have unique values.

If it was a query output, you just need to use `DISTINCT` keyword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`id`) FROM `table` WHERE `SomeCondition`='Value';
```

You can also try by using `GROUP BY`, but using `DISTINCT` is much faster IMHO. ([What's faster, SELECT DISTINCT or GROUP BY in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/581521))

Comment: Thnks for your help

Comment: YEah..I got the answer..Thnks :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have 2 tables with us:
1) student: Fields are as follows:
a) id: INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
b) name: VARCHAR
Sample Data:

```
student  
id | name
----------  
1  | A  
2  | B  
3  | C
```

2) marks: Fields are as follows:
a) id: INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
b) sid: INTEGER FOREIGN KEY (refers to id field from student table)
c) subject: VARCHAR
d) marks: INTEGER
Sample Data:

```
marks:
id | sid | subject | marks  
--------------------------
1  | 1   | s1      | 40

2  | 2   | s2      | 50

3  | 2   | s1      | 60

4  | 2   | s2      | 70

5  | 3   | s1      | 80
```

Use below query to get distinct student id's with referring records in descending order:

```
SELECT `student`.`id`, COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM `student` INNER JOIN `marks` ON (`student`.`id` = `marks`.`sid`) WHERE 1 GROUP BY `student`.`id` ORDER BY `total` DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use group by to get unique ids.

**SQL Query:**

```
select id from table group by id;
```

Comment: Is this the whole answer?

Comment: to get unique ids from the table this query is fine and VASIS want to get output in single SQL query.

Comment: Hey, before anything, I **didn't downvote** your answer. Okay, you forgot considering the `ORDER BY`...