# Mysql group table with two column

Tags: mysql

I need to group my table, my table had lot of columns but i am showing only two column jtcno and projectno. The primary key is roeid, it contain an auto increment numbers.  My table structure is as given below

```
+-------+-----------+
| jtcno | projectno |
+-------+-----------+
| 8229  |     10636 |
| 8230  |     10636 |
| 8231  |     10636 |
| 8229  |     10637 |
| 8230  |     10637 |
| 8231  |     10637 |
| 8229  |     10637 |
| 8230  |     10637 |
| 8231  |     10637 |
+-------+-----------+
```

I need to group the table according to jtcno as follows

```
+-------+-----------+
| jtcno | projectno |
+-------+-----------+
| 8229  |     10636 |
| 8230  |     10636 |
| 8231  |     10636 |
| 8229  |     10637 |
| 8230  |     10637 |
| 8231  |     10637 |
+-------+-----------+
```

Can anyone help me to write the query.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY? And see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I had an id row, that is my primay key.

Comment: Please amend your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the desired result, you need to group by both the columns

1. If there no index

```
SELECT DISTINCT jtcno, projectno
FROM my_table
ORDER BY jtcno, projectno;
```

2. If there an index

```
SELECT jtcno, projectno
FROM my_table
GROUP BY jtcno, projectno;
```

Comment: There is no problem in sql for which the above is a valid solution. In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. If you want DISTINCT results, use DISTINCT.

Comment: @Strawberry I have corrected my answer, I was not knowing this

Comment: @Strawberry AS far as I have read `DISTINCT` is preferable if there is no index and `GROUP BY` is preferable if there is an index.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581521/whats-faster-select-distinct-or-group-by-in-mysql

Comment: Copy of my answer.  Your original query was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

This is the query you seem to want here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT jtcno, projectno
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY projectno, jtcno;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
select distinct jtcno, projectno from tablename order by jtcno
```